# Python Split() IndexError

Tags: python, split, index-error

The falling code is giving me the results I want but it keeps giving me the same error and the program doesn´t complete.

```
totalIdadesM = 0
totalIdadesH = 0

countM = 0
countH = 0

with open("info.txt", "r") as infoFile:
    for line in infoFile:
        if line[1] == "M":
            for line in infoFile:
                dados = line.split("=")
                print(dados)
                idade, peso = dados[1].split(",")

                print(idade)
                print(peso)


                if idade.isdigit():
                    totalIdadesM += int(idade)
                    countM += 1

        print(countM)
def calcMedia(total, num):
    media = total / num
    return media
```

And that's the error

> ['Ana', '24,55\n']
>
> 24   55
>
> ['Ines', '30,60\n']
>
> 30   60
>
> ['Sofia', '18,49\n']
>
> 18   49
>
> ['Carla', '44,64\n']
>
> 44   64
>
> ['\n']
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "ex4.1.py", line 13, in
>   
>       idade, peso = dados[1].split(",") IndexError: list index out of range

The input is like this:

> [Mulheres]   Ana=24,55  Ines=30,60  Sofia=18,49  Carla=44,64
>
> [Homens]   Joao=20,75  Tiago=55,80  Quim=59,69

Comment: Well it prints `['\n']` right before the error, so that's probably `dados`, and clearly in that case `dados[1]` is an error. That means that `line` is `'\n'`.

Answer (score 1):

Your code's hitting an empty line. You can skip all empty lines with this:

```
for line in infoFile:
    line = line.strip()
    if not line: # empty line
        continue # skip the body and go staring to next iteration

    dados = line.split("=")
    ...
```

One thing I'm not sure about is why you're iterating over `infoFile` *twice*. When you're iterating, you're reading from it, and here, for example, the first line will be skipped:

```
for line in infoFile:
    # read first line
    if line[1] == "M":
        for line in infoFile:
            # first line has already been read, so read the second line,
            # thus skipping the first one altogether
            ...
        # the loop will be exited when there'll be no more data to read
    # so the outer loop will terminate since there's nothing to iterate over anymore
```